# TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: minimum_price

Tags: python, django

Here is what I am trying to do:

User (business) have multiple article items and I am trying to find and show the minimum priced item inside the User class.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, default='undefinedusername')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
        
    @property
    def minimum_price(self):
        return self.articles.all().aggregate(Min('price'))['price__min']

class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    minimum_price = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
                  
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs.get('id') == self.context['request'].user.pk:
            return attrs
        raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
```

**Views.py**

```
class PublicUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['minimum_price']
```

But here is the error that I get:

```
TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: minimum_price
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can not use `minimum_price` in `filterset`, since this has no "translation" in the database.

Comment: Is there a workaround for the algorithm? @willeM_VanOnsem

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `minimum_price` in `filterset`, since this has no "translation" in the database.

You probably should use a custom `FilterSet`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Min


class PublicUserFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    minimum_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(method='filter_minimum_price')

    def filter_minimum_price(self, queryset, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if value is not None:
            return queryset.alias(_min_price=Min('articles__price')).filter(
                _min_price__lte=value
            )
        return queryset

    class Meta:
         model = User


class PublicUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = PublicUserFilterSet
```

That being said, using `@property`s that need to do database queries is probably not ideal anyway, since it can introduce the so-called *N+1 problem* where for a `QueryS3et` of *N* items, it will need to do *N+1* items to retrieve all items, and determine the corresponding `minimum_price`.

Comment: ```AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.filters' has no attribute 'FilterSet'```

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: wrong module: `import django_filters as filters`.

Comment: ```AttributeError: module 'django_filters' has no attribute 'DecimalFilter'.```